# HashPrefix + Html5Mode creates loop (Maximum call stack size exceeded)

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

this is my first post here and my explanation may be a little rusty so please forgive me in advance.

I'm having a problem with AngularJs and C#. I'm following a step by step of a tutorial (https://www.codeproject.com/articles/806500/getting-started-with-angularjs-and-asp-net-mvc-p?fid=1866601&df=90&mpp=25&sort=Position&spc=Relaxed&prof=True&view=Normal&fr=51#xx0xx) because I'm new at C# and I'm trying to understand how to convine these two languages.
At a point the tutorial wants to clean that scotch (#) in the URL to make it look cleaner, here is where it creates a $locationProvider in the config of the app:

```
var configFunction = function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider, $locationProvider)
{
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!').html5Mode(true);
    $routeProvider
        .when('/routeOne', {
            templateUrl: 'RouteDemo/One'
        })
        .when('/routeTwo/:donuts', {
            templateUrl: function (params) { return 'RouteDemo/Two?donuts=' + params.donuts; }
        })
        .when('/routeThree', {
            templateUrl: 'RouteDemo/Three'
        })
        .when('/login', {
            templateUrl: '/Account/Login',
            controller: LoginController
        })
        .when('/register', {
            templateUrl: '/Account/Register',
            controller: RegisterController
        });

        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('AuthHttpResponseInterceptor');
}

configFunction.$inject = ['$routeProvider','$httpProvider', '$locationProvider'];
MVCTrial.config(configFunction);
```

And here is where the error of angular appear (Maximum call stack size exceeded) whenever I try to go to "routeTwo" will get in this infinite loop

index.cshtml of the links:

```
<ul>
            <li><a href="/routeOne">Route One</a></li>
            <li><a href="/routeTwo/6">Route Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="/routeThree">Route Three</a></li>
        </ul>
```

I just posted where $locationProvider is given because is not complex coding behind and I linked the tutorial I'm following. But if you need more information please let me know!

Sorry for this long post! and Thanks for reading and taking time to help :)!

Comment: `templateUrl:'RouteDemo/One'` - check the `html` returned by `c#` - is it returning partial html or whole document with scripts included? if it returning whole document then the script woud executes recursively

Comment: They are all created by partial views